# N64 graphical glitches in RetroArch/Mupen64Plus-next

Tags: technical-issues, emulation, nintendo-64, zelda-ocarina-of-time, retroarch

I was playing Ocarina of Time successfully, but now when I play I get graphical glitches:

https://imgur.com/XB5MN0P

Notice the spinning N logo is already glitchy, as well as the obvious OOT-specific issues.

I did experiment with trying to load a different core and content, so maybe that caused it, but I don't know which settings will have been impacted. I since did "Load Content" for Mupen64Plus-next, which is what I believe I was using in the first place, but now there are these glitches.

What's wrong and how do I fix it?